# Beginner : Where to copy the asp.net dll file from visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll, chromium-embedded

I can easily write an asp.net code. I hit the visual studio RUN button and I see my website in Chrome or any other browser. But how do I do this without visual studio? I don't get an exe file, only the dll. I think, this must be copied somewhere.

Idea is to run (any) programm, which causes a special page to show my website (with OPC-data) on a local computer. Like an exe file.

To give more detail: I want to run some Web site code in a CEF (chromium embedded framefork) so that it looks like a normal executable. It will run only on a local computer (in fact a machine). This is static. But some information have to be provided dynamically by an OPC client. This will be read with VB and displayed via ASP.NET. The first application reads the data via AJAX. **So I think what I need is some kind of local server (like wamp) which has to be started in the background.**  I found a batch file to start WebDev.WebServer40.exe. But this could not be the right way. A batch file sounds like stone age.

-->c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0

Comment: Are you looking to host your website somewhere, or are you looking to distribute code that users would run locally?

Comment: When you run the asp.net site within Visual Studio you either use IISExpress or the full blown IIS to host your application. With the new version of ASP.NET (vNext) you will be able to self-host the application using OWIN however I don't think there is a way to do this currently without something hosting your website.

Comment: I found, that it has something to do with the IIS Manager. Could be possible, that I only have to set a path to my folder. Then I can start with localhost:nnnn/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have IIS Manger installed, yes? If not, you can go to Control Panel \ Programs and Features and turn this Windows feature on.  From within IIS, find the Default Website node and underneath that create a new application (this way it inherits the correct permissions).  Point the application's start path to wherever your web app lives on your hard drive (the root folder that contains your app's web.config file).  Anyway, that's one way to deploy your app locally.